# IIS Rewrite SEF Urls with subfolders

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I've searched around quite a bit without any luck so decided it was time I asked.

I have a situation where a client wants SEF urls

`www.somesite.com/sef_rewriting`

`www.somesite.com/foo`

work fine - the problem is that what happens if `sef_rewriting` can also be a directory?

`www.somesite.com/sef_rewriting/removing_file_extensions`

IIS will automatically add a trailing slash if someone requests the following url: `www.somesite.com/sef_rewriting` and redirect to the sub-directory.

e.g. Structure

```
>wwwroot
    -index.html
    -foo.html
    -sef_rewriting.html
    >sef_rewriting
         -removing_file_extensions.html
```

How do I create a rule to check to see if the requested extensionless URL matches a file with a specified extension say in this case (html) and serve up that file and only if the file doesn't exists should IIS redirect to the sub-directory?

I found the following rule online it works for the basic case but not with subdirectories with the same name as files.

```
<rule name="SEF REWRITE html">
    <match url=".*" negate="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(/[^.]*|\.(html))$" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:0}.html" />
</rule>
```

any help would be appreciated..

note: the file and directory naming scheme can not be changed.

**UPDATE: Edited for clarity**

The rules must handle the following conditions

1. www.mysite.com - serve index.html
2. www.mysite.com/foo - serve foo.html
3. www.mysite.com/sef_rewriting  - serve sef_rewriting.html
4. www.mysite.com/sef_rewriting/removing_file_extensions - serve
   removing_file_extensions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have, with the help of many people and the htaccess import wizard (didn't even know that existed!), answered my own question.

```
<rule name="SEF RULE 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />
</rule>
<rule name="SEF Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/index.html" />
</rule>
```

Rule 1: checks for the existence of a file with the defined extension, if it exists it serves that file

Rule 2: checks to see if the "default" file exists when requesting a directory e.g. www.mysite.com/ will check to see if www.mysite.com/index.html exists and if yes serve that.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could use below url rewrite rule.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="SEF REWRITE html" >
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions  logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" >
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Result:
[image]

But entering the sitename in the url, the site will not working.

I suggest you could also add below url rewrite to set the index page.

```
<rule name="showindex" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([a-z]+[.]com)$"/>
      </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}/index.html" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: the showindex rule doesn't work in conjunction with the above