# Show Full URL path automictically when browsing. IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

We are using IIS 10
I have a user that wants their site and subsites to show the full URL path when browsing. For example, if you go to mysite.domain.com/ or mysite.domain.com/subsite/ it will show you mysite.domain/file.html or mysite.domain.com/subsite/file.html in the URL
Is there a way in IIS to tell it to show the full path or append the file somehow?

The reasoning for this within Google Analytics there getting reports for both sites and just want the mysite.domain.com/file.html and not mysite.domain.com/
I think the main files there concerned about are the index.html files being seen in URL.

I know a little about URL Rewrite rules but by far no expert for sure but I can't figure out if this is possible or not. Thanks, any advice.

We are using IIS 10

I tried to basic redirect rule in URL rewrite, but I am not sure if that it what I am really asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<rule name="Rule SEF Redirect Subfolders/Index.html Rule " enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.html" matchType="IsFile" />
</conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}index.html" />
  </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want redirect from `mysite.domain.com/` to `mysite.domain.com/file.html`, you can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/file.html" />
</rule>
```

This is test result:

[image]

If you want redirect from `mysite.domain.com/subsite/` to `mysite.domain.com/subsite/file.html` or`mysite.domain.com/subsite` to `mysite.domain.com/subsite/file.html`, you can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^(.*)$" />
         <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/([^/]+)" />
         </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="/{C:1}/file.html" />
</rule>
```

This is test result:

[image]

Comment: Hello, Samwu I am getting Error too many redirects page for a few seconds and then it goes to a webpage that says Bad Request-Invalid URL HTTP ERROR 400. The request URL is invalid. The Url path has the file multiple times at the end as well. Example http://mysite.domain.com/index.htmlindex.html.. This is what I have in the rule <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^.*$" />
     <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mysite.domain.com$" />
     </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:0}index.html" redirectType="Permanent" />

Comment: `mysite.domain.com/index.htmlindex.html` This should be mysite.domain.com/index.html? and does the above url `mysite.domain.com/`  and  `mysite.domain.com/subsite/` have a `/` at the end? If this is the case, then new url rewrite rule are needed.

Comment: when I used the rule, it would appear in the browser URL mysite.domain.com/index.htmlindex.html..etc Even though it was actually mysite.domain.com/index.html after the redirect.  Yes, the sites do end with a / at the end. Do you think that's where the problem lies? We are wanting mysite.domain.com/ to go to mysite.domain.com/index.html and any other subsite that end with / to go to its index.html file. Example mysite.domain.com/subsite/ go to mysite.domain.com/subsite/index.html , mysite.domain.com/subsite2/ go to mysite.domain.com/subsite2/index.html .  I hope this make more sense now.

Comment: Additional information on my previous comment about the mysite.domain.com/index.htmlindex.html..etc showing in the URL. After removing the {R:0} from the /{R:0}index.html that stopped and just went to the Error_Too_many_redirects but showed as mysite.domain.com/index.html.

Comment: You can refer to the above rules, I created two rules according to different needs. For the convenience of my test, I use localhost.

Comment: I think we a getting closer on the subsite rule. It is redirecting from mysite.domain.com/subsite/ to mysite.domain.com/subsite/index.html. However, I am still getting the Err_too_many_redirects when browsing to the url. I was able to do a trace log and it does not appear to be showing failure. Do you think is another IIS setting or the condition pattern in the url rule? 
Failure Reason STATUS_CODE
Trigger Status 301
Final Status  301
Url http://localhost:80/subsite/index.html
-Errors & Warnings 
No Errors or Warnings were found

Comment: ..I also looked at the developer tools on Edge and when browsing to the site mysite.domain.com/subsite you can see several 301 requests to the index.html file in the network console. I think it is looping for some reason.

Comment: Clear your browser's cache and try again, and you can disable other rules in your url rewrite to make sure they don't affect this redirect.

Comment: This is what I have done to troubleshoot so far with no luck. Still in a redirect loop
• Cleared all cache and used different browsers
• The test site only had the 1 rule enabled, “test1”. Removed all 
         other rules that we were testing
• Brought up a new IIS server and created a site with the rule.
• Created a new file called file.html in a subsite and tried to set 
  url="/{C:1}/file.html" to see if the redirect would work with a different 
  file other than index.html.
Thanks for helping me figure this out. I have worked on this all day today with the same results.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. I have posted the answer let me know if you see something that could cause an issue. Thank you so much for all your help. I based it off of a rule I found from garyrgilbert on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793309/iis-rewrite-sef-urls-with-subfolders/54828836#54828836